# Pycharm not finding installed module (requests)

Tags: python, python-requests

I am migrating some python code to another project...

`pip freeze`

```
...
requests==2.23.0
...
```

In pycharm when I try to run the project it says it can not find the above module.
I have invalidated the cache to re-index, but this did not help. The module shows up in pycharm's installed module list, and the syntax highlighter recognizes it as installed.

Comment: are you running the script within a venv (virtual environment)? I recall PyCharm does attempt to use one by default when starting a new project. The way to check is open terminal in PyCharm and if there's a (venv) or similar around the terminal prompt.

Comment: @n1c9 yes it is using the virtual environment.

Comment: if you're running that `pip freeze` command locally (i.e. not in the PyCharm terminal), then it may be that you need to run the `pip install requests` within the PyCharm terminal using the venv.  You may run into this problem when you have installed a package locally, but haven't installed it within the venv - that's my only idea to resolving this.

Comment: @n1c9 I have done it in both locations. Both locations say it is installed

Comment: if you open Settings in PyCharm, then go to project: (your project name), then Project Interpreter, does it show in the list  of packages there?

Comment: @n1c9 yes, it also shows it when I do pip freeze in the console